# How can I starting activity with page_two

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How can I implement an `Activity` with page_ two? What can I do?

Here's an example: [image: This image]

So far, my activity code looks like this:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this));
```

CustomPagerAdapter.java

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    ModelObject modelObject = ModelObject.values()[position];
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(modelObject.getLayoutResId(), collection, false);
    collection.addView(layout);
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    collection.removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ModelObject.values().length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    ModelObject customPagerEnum = ModelObject.values()[position];
    return mContext.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId());
}
}
```

And ModelObject.java

```
 public enum ModelObject {


BLUE(R.string.blue, R.layout.page_one),
GREEN(R.string.green, R.layout.page_two),
RED(R.string.blue, R.layout.page_tree);

private int mTitleResId;
private int mLayoutResId;


ModelObject(int titleResId, int layoutResId) {
    mTitleResId = titleResId;
    mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
}

public int getTitleResId() {
    return mTitleResId;
}

public int getLayoutResId() {
    return mLayoutResId;
}

}
```

How  can I solve this ?
I changed list but I didn't; 
So how ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Please edit your question. Fix the spelling. Include pictures directly, not as link. Most importantly: clarify your question. Tell us what you've done so far, and what specifically you

Comment: Call [`setCurrentItem()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int)) on your `ViewPager`